# Show $\operatorname{diag}(BA)=B\cdot\operatorname{diag}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $B$ is an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix.

How to show that for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, $$\operatorname{diag}(BA)=B\cdot \operatorname{diag}(A).$$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $B$ is diagonal, $B_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$. Then

$$\mbox{diag}(BA)_i=\sum_{k}B_{ik}A_{ki}=B_{ii}A_{ii}.$$

$$[B\cdot\mbox{diag}(A)]_{i}=\sum_{k}B_{ik}\mbox{diag}(A)_k=\sum_k B_{ik}A_{kk}=B_{ii}A_{ii}.$$

To clarify, the sums reduce to a single term: $k=i$.